# How to exchange simple text files with Messages, WhatsApp with any recipient

Tags: software-recommendation, messages, text, file-transfer, whatsapp.app

I often have to send simple text files to recipients working on Mac, iPhone, PC running Linux, Windows, mobile running Android. These files are slightly formatted (just tabs and returns) to be easily readable without requiring heavy or untrustable tools.

I would like them to be able to read them as straight forwardly as possible, i.e. without having to make them a lecture on computer tools to install. The working expected environment of recipients is the basic one:
no Cloud sharing (no iCloud, no Dropbox).
The file names should be self explanatory and not distorted, example:

- meeting 25/01/2019.agenda
- authentication project.schedule

Currently upon sending such a file with `Messages` or `WhatsApp`, my recipients just see an attachment, but its content isn't displayed, and worse, none of the target OS is able to present a choice of application able to display a simple text file.
If I copy and paste the content of files to sent, the name of the file is lost, the content is completly damaged.

Is their any mean to achieve this simple and basic need with either an application (for me to install and use) or through a basic function of iOS or MacOS I didn't found yet.

Comment: What happens if the file name ends in .text (e.g. authentication project.schedule.text)?

Comment: This is the beginning of a good answer. If I add a `.txt` suffix, then iOS is able to display it directly within `Messages` and `WhatsApp`. Android doesn’t display it directly and suggest heavy and untrustable applications.